# How do I revert Mac locations?

Tags: mac, settings, zsh

[image]

Hi!

I was hoping someone could help with my issue. Basically my Locations has changed on my Mac. I can't remember exactly what it was before, possibly my name but now it is showing bazooka. I think this was because I was playing around when I changed from bash to zsh and unfortunately do not know how to revert it. It means my terminal has become funky and I don't have permissions to open text-files/make changes.

Would really appreciate some help as I can only thing of restoring my Mac to factory settings may be a resolution.

Thanks!

Second Edit:

After changing the name in Sharing, I am still seeing 'Bazooka'

[image]

Comment: If you go to **System Preferences** > **Sharing** > **Computer Name:**, is it showing **bazooka**? If yes, then that's where you can change it back to whatever it was or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Hi @user3439894,
Thanks for responding!

I have changed the compute name through your suggestions, so I thank you for that. My computer is still pointing to this new Bazooka name in other places however, and I still don't have permissions to edit files on my own computer under my name, as I think it's pointing to Bazooka as the main user. I've uploaded a new photo to the initial post..

Thanks!

Comment: @Tom I've just written up an answer, but the gist is that the iCloud list your showing doesn't update very quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer name can be changed in System Preferences > Sharing. This name may take a while to propagate to Apple ID device list.

Your hard drive name (not your computer name) looks set to Macintosh HD–this can be changed by simply right clicking and choosing rename.

Your account name can be identified in System Preferences > Users & Groups. If the information on this screen is incorrect, the easiest solution is to make a new account and transfer stuff manually. It is possible to change this without making a new account, just not trivial.

Comment: Thanks Ezekiel. It seems you are right.

I do have some other issues currently since moving over to the zsh, but for the purposes of this question you've answered it.

So thank you for that!